# Create custom view like wheel component

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have seen this [1](http://www.google.gr/imgres?q=tichutoo&um=1&hl=el&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=852&tbm=isch&tbnid=iFS8AI17xo5-oM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.androidzoom.com/android_games/cards_and_casino/tichutoo_hmdx.html&docid=RjkNxw8WdAkx4M&w=320&h=480&ei=kceVTpOnOYLg4QSG0PCmCA&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=178&page=1&tbnh=152&tbnw=105&start=0&ndsp=28&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0&tx=76&ty=26) in several applications and I would like to ask what components were used..I am talking about the 3 lists at the bottom looking like a wheel...the first can affect the 3rd because the sum must be 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom component.You can make your own component like that.
Here is a demo application for wheel view component

[Click here](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/)

Comment: i was looking exactly for this..i haven't heard of that widget!

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you provided looks like it's using a modified version of the [android wheel widget](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/).

Having them update in regard to each other is a modification than can be done by extending the **AbstractWheelTextAdapter** included with the widget.